# Send List<String> from iOS to C# WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, ios, objective-c, webmethod

I'm trying to send data to a C# WebMethod that expects a parameter in the form of List from an iOS app. What's the best / correct way to format that data on the app side?

Comment: Does the .NET side have the ability to deserialize a JSON value? If so, use that. Are any other non-.NET clients making use of this WebMethod?

Comment: To elaborate, I have no direct access to the .NET side of things. I just know one of the parameters I'm sending up is a List<String> on that end, and I'm not sure how to build that on the iOS end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this, it turns out just adding an NSMutableArray to the call comes out to an equivalent JSON request using JSONKit, so I was able to get it working.